# What should be correct unambiguous server side behavior for missing optional field values when updating a record?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, architecture

We have an Angular + Laravel 5 application and we attempt to adhere to RESTful design (although, to be honest, we don't implement it fully).

I noticed that with time we have accumulated some inconsistencies for processing empty values for optional fields when updating a record. Here's what happens:

- in some cases programmer just ignores the fact that optional values are missing and passes only the received values to Laravel model. This results in preserving the old value unchanged in the database.
- in some cases programmer tries to be smart and assumes - if the optional field was not received, then the user might want to fill it with some global default value (which usually means `null` ). This results in overwriting the old value with default value in the database. What's confusing - in some cases this behavior is explicitly requested by our customer for some specific fields - that is, if user did not send anything to our web API, we should overwrite the old value with `null`.
- in some cases programmer tries to prevent the ambiguity and rejects the request even if optional value is missing (we are using custom `present` Laravel validation rule for this purpose). If user really wants to fill the value with default, then explicit `null` (or whatever the default value is) should be sent from the web form. This usually is not a problem when updating because then the web form usually will be already filled with the old values, but it gets messy when saving new records because Angular by default does not send unfilled form fields to the server. So we have to force it and thus we end up with our Javascript models filled with lots of model initialization code like `{ someOptionalField:null, someOptionalField2:null, ... }`. Some programmers in our team argue that this looks ugly. I had an idea to extend Angular's ngModel directive to implicitly fill nulls in undefined model values, so they get always sent to the server. But I'm not sure if this is the correct solution because I haven't seen other Angular programmers on the Internet do something like that.

**What is the correct way to solve this in unambiguous manner and to make things clear for both server side programmers and users of our web API? Are there any known design patterns or best practices for this?**

Comment: IMO defining your view models should be done, its goes hand in hand with define any variable before using. fyi VueJS forces this. Serverside, if the value is not required and sent up empty or not at all then its nulled, no exception, you should be defining your model so your know whats expected and missing to be nulled. Basically normalise..

Comment: You first populate the data with the current values, then overwrite them, right?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  Yes, Laravel Eloquent is made that way that it reads all fields first and then you can fill new values for some fields and it will update the changed values only (so called dirty checking). While this is simple and transparent for programmers, it also can add to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I myself and also we at work handle this on the backend side. If there is an optional field, which MUST have a value (sounds funny right?), it will get set to its default value if the given input is empty or simply not there. 
Just ignoring the fields or setting the value of old data to null is undesirable like you said and should not be done.

I like creating the default values at the top of my validation functions and just override it with the new one if its present. If there is an old value, use it over the default:

```
1. Validation progress starts
2. If value is given - use it
2.1 If not given, look if there is an old value for this field and if so, use it
2.2 If still no value, use default
```

Therefore you don't get errors because a field is empty/not set or at least don't have to worry about it. And also you can handle defaults/old values properly.

The problem with you having angular not sending empty fields could be compensated if you serialize the full form and send it to the server. 
If this doesn't work as simple as it does in jQuery (form.serialize()) or still having empty fields, why not loop over all form elements and creating the JSON/form data by hand?

This answer is mostly opinion based (as the question itself is), but I hope it helps you!

Comment: Why is nulling a value `undesirable and should not be done`? So when it comes to outputting that data when the user/customer removed it, the value is still there. thats a bug to me.

Comment: Yes you are right, if the user removes it and the value is not a MUST, then this is ok. But if its a field, which has to have a default value you cant just null it (except if null is/should be the default).

Comment: Oh yeah, but I thought the OP was talking about optional fields, not ones which are validated.

Comment: Well yes, he kinda did. But you still have to validate optional fields if given. I´d even call it still validation if you are checking for old/default value.